# Elasticsearch result difference with one 's' in keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am having a problem while fetching records from elasticsearch 5.0, before that our system was working with haystack and 1.x ES. The query Haystack generated was AND OR keywords query. But now I created all queries for ES 5.0. Query seems to work fine except the results are different. I am feeling its due to some type. But is newbie in ES.curl -

XGET 'https://xxxxxx.yyyyy.com/haystack/_count?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"from" : 0, "size" : 400, "query": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"date": {"gt": "2017-10-27T00:00:00+00:00", "lte": "2017-11-27T00:00:00+00:00"}}}, {"bool": {"should": [{"terms": {"mentions_twitter_handle": ["dartalert", "dartmedia"]}}, {"terms": {"mentions_instagram_handle": ["dartdaily"]}}, {"terms": {"mentions_fbid": ["82233029811"]}}]}}]}}}'

its output is

{
  "count" : 383,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 15,
    "successful" : 15,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}

XGET 'https://xxxxxx.yyyyy.com/haystack/_count?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"from" : 0, "size" : 400, "query": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"date": {"gt": "2017-10-27T00:00:00+00:00", "lte": "2017-11-27T00:00:00+00:00"}}}, {"bool": {"should": [{"terms": {"mentions_twitter_handle": ["dartalerts", "dartmedia"]}}, {"terms": {"mentions_instagram_handle": ["dartdaily"]}}, {"terms": {"mentions_fbid": ["82233029811"]}}]}}]}}}'

only with dartalerts, the count is different

{
  "count" : 315,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 15,
    "successful" : 15,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}

I have attached mapping and results in this dropbox files. Can anybody help me. I am really in trouble.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/maa38lty49uljgp/es_question.zip?dl=0 is the link to all results files.

Comment: is this really related to `django-haystack`?

Comment: Why I added django-haystack, because the previous system which returned proper number of records was on django-haystack. But the current one is with Elasticsearch-dsl.